# the location of the element in the array that contains the maximum

Tags: java

guys how do i find out the location of the maximum in an array, i know the maximum, but i need to know where its location.

```
class maximumofarray
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    double maximum;
    int i;
    double [] a={1.5,2.3,4.2,-9.4,2.0,12.9,-5.0,12.9,-0.1,-15.0,0.0};
    maximum=a[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
      {
      if (a[i] > maximum)
        {
        maximum = a[i];
        }

      }
    System.out.println("The maximum element is "+maximum);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the below steps:

(1) Declare one more variable (`maxLocation`) which is required to collect the location of the `maximum`

(2) When you are assigning the maximum (i.e., `a[i] > maximum`), also collect the location of the max element as `maxLocation`

**The Code is given below:**

```
double maximum;
int i;
int maxLocation =0;
double [] a={1.5,2.3,4.2,-9.4,2.0,12.9,-5.0,12.9,-0.1,-15.0,0.0};
maximum=a[0];
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
  if (a[i] > maximum)
    {
       maximum = a[i]; //assign maximum value
       maxLocation = i; //Also, collect the location as well to maxLocation
    }

  }
System.out.println("The maximum element is "+maximum);
System.out.println("The maximum element is "+maxLocation);

}
```

Comment: One modification: assign maxLocation = 0 at the start, because if a[0] will be the greatest of the array, then in the last line will be print null value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a second variable...

```
double maximum;
int locationOfMaximum;
int i;
double [] a={1.5,2.3,4.2,-9.4,2.0,12.9,-5.0,12.9,-0.1,-15.0,0.0};
maximum=a[0];
locationOfMaximum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
  if (a[i] > maximum)
    {
    maximum = a[i];
    locationOfMaximum = i;
    }

  }
System.out.println("The maximum element is "+maximum+";  it appears at index "+locationOfMaximum);
```

For the record, there are a few more changes I would suggest to make the code more readable...

```
double [] a={1.5,2.3,4.2,-9.4,2.0,12.9,-5.0,12.9,-0.1,-15.0,0.0};

double maximum = Double.MIN_VALUE;  // Or Double maximum = null;
int locationOfMaximum = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] > maximum) {
    maximum = a[i];
    locationOfMaximum = i;
  }

}
System.out.println("The maximum element is "+maximum+";  it appears at index "+locationOfMaximum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use utilit method `Arrays.sort(a)` to sort the array. then the max element will stay at lat index.

```
double maximum;
int i;
double [] a={1.5,2.3,4.2,-9.4,2.0,12.9,-5.0,12.9,-0.1,-15.0,0.0};

Arrays.sort(a);

System.out.println("The maximum element is "+a[a.length-1]);
```

Comment: It's very non-effective, there are some other methods, more effective, than sorting.

Comment: @KamilGryboś So you are trying to say this utility method present in JDK is not effective and gives less performance.This internally uses " Dual-Pivot Quicksort" You can always check performance giving time stamps and checking the time taken for code. When you already have a method in your jar we shouldnt use unnecessary lines of codes.

Comment: in this context. Not globally.

Comment: @sushuber U are absolutely correct if this piece of code is a piece of a big project. But it clearly seems here its asked by someone who is learning java not a working professional. So as a learner a person needs to write algorithms at this stage rather than using APIs. +1 for mentioning the internal algorithm this API uses.